# Trying to retrieve multple JDBC results

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jdbc

So I'm trying to print out all of the hospitals in my program that deal with certain severity levels of medical conditions (High, medium and low), which are passed from another part of my program.

Initially, it'll find the correct severity level, and so it'll check against another table in the database to find hospitals and print them. However, it is only printing one of the hospitlals (there are two for high severity which Im testing with) but not the other one.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like my looping is wrong.

Thanks.

```
// Create selection query, get relevant hospitals
String select = "SELECT * FROM hospitals WHERE hospitalSeverityHandling = '" + medicalCondition + "'";


// Get results hospitals in the database
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(select);

// When hospitals have been found 

if (results.next())
{
    results.first();

    // Get hospitals with relevant severity
    //String hospital = results.getString("hospitalName");
    //System.out.println(hospital);

    // Respond to user, get hospital selection
    // TODO Hospital Selection
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A list of hospitals have been retrieved for severity level: " + medicalCondition, "Select available hospital", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);   

    // Loop hospitals
    while(results.next())
    {
        String hospital = results.getString("hospitalName");
        System.out.println(hospital);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `results.first()` before the `while` loop. I think you are skipping the first record. Also, your query looks vulnerable to injection. Consider using a prepared statement. Consider using try-with-resources as well.

Comment: Thanks. Someone did already comment with a fix, however when I tried to mark it as correct it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one record because you are using results.next() two times.

Rather, you can use it as follows:

```
   String select = "SELECT * FROM hospitals WHERE    
       hospitalSeverityHandling = '" + medicalCondition + "'";

    // Get results hospitals in the database
    ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(select);

     // Loop hospitals
        while(results.next())
        {
            String hospital = results.getString("hospitalName");
            System.out.println(hospital);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
while(results.next())               
            {
                // Put into interactive list
                String hospital = results.getString("hospitalName");

                // Loops each hospital via popup, needs to be added to a selection menu
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hospital, "Hospital List", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```